# Fibonacci Homework - java

Tags: java, testing, for-loop

We had to create a Fibonacci system. Could you tell me what I did wrong? It gives me an error under the while loop but I'm sure it is the way I constructed my variables.

```
public class Chapter3 {
    public static void main (String args[]){  
        int numFn;//CREATE NUMBER OF FN, SUM OF FN, AND AVERAGE   
        int average[]=new int [0];
        int sumFn []=new int [0];//ARRAY OF SUMFN        
        numFn = 1;//ASSIGN FN AS 1           
        int x = 0;//NUMBERIN SIDE FN ARRAY         
        int Fn []=new int[16];//CREATE FN ARRAY       
        Fn [0]=0;    

        while (numFn <15){
            Fn[x]= Fn[x]-Fn[x-1];//SET THE CURRENT FN NUMBER
            sumFn [x]=sumFn[x]+(sumFn[x-1]+Fn[x]);//SET CURRENT SUMFN NUMBER
            average [x]= sumFn[x]/numFn;

            System.out.println(numFn +"/t" +Fn+"/t" +sumFn+"/t" +average);
            x++;
            numFn++;
        }
    }
}
```

well i changed it up using youre guys's advice yet the first ouput is 1 then 0 for everything, used this code :

```
           public class Chapter3 {
        public static void main (String args[]){
          int numFn;//CREATE NUMBER OF FN, SUM OF FN, AND AVERAGE
        int average[]=new int [16];
        int sumFn []=new int [16];//ARRAY OF SUMFN
        numFn = 1;//ASSIGN FN AS 1
        int x = 1;//NUMBERIN SIDE FN ARRAY
        int Fn []=new int[16];//CREATE FN ARRAY
        Fn [0]=0;



    while (numFn <15){
        Fn[x]= Fn[x]-Fn[x-1];//SET THE CURRENT FN NUMBER
        sumFn [x]=sumFn[x]+(sumFn[x-1]+Fn[x]);//SET CURRENT SUMFN NUMBER
        average [x]= sumFn[x]/numFn;

        System.out.println(numFn +"\t" +Fn[x]+"\t" +sumFn[x]+"\t" +average[x]);
        x++;
        numFn++;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you tell _us_ what error you have?

Comment: `new int [0]` is an array with exactly 0 items, this must be wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that you're writing things without understanding them first. I.E. `new int[0]`. I'd suggest reading and researching first, and coding afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Several problems :

1. new int[0] means an empty array, which is not what you
       want.
2. X value is 0 on the first loop execution, so Fn[X-1] is Fn[-1], which
       would cause an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Can you also be more explicit about the error you encounter please?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after (this code starts with 1 and 1 and prints the first 20 terms)...

```
public class Fibonacci {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        int n0 = 1, n1 = 1, n2;    
        System.out.print(n0 + " " + n1 + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) { // Loop for the next 18 terms
            n2 = n1 + n0; //The next term is the sum of the previous two terms
            System.out.print(n2 + " ");       
            n0 = n1; // The first previous number becomes the second previous number...       
            n1 = n2; // ...and the current number becomes the previous number     
        }     
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

As for your errors, read the other answers. Their advice is good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your sumFn array is declared with a length of 0.  So any time you try to add any element to it, you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

There are *several* problems with the code, even after fixing the one that causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException I doubt it will work. For starters, you must initialize the arrays you're using in the correct size:

```
int average[]=new int [16];
int sumFn []=new int [16];
```

The "x" variable should start in 1:

```
int x = 1;
```

Also, it's not clear what do you want to print, anyway the `println()` statement should be fixed

```
System.out.println(numFn +"\t" +Fn[x]+"\t" +sumFn[x] + "\t" +average[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was really helpful resolving the Fibonacci sequence exercise. However doesn't print the zero, so I added here...

```
/*
 * FibonacciSequence.java
 * ----------------------
 * This program displays the values in the Fibonacci sequnece from F0 to F15.
*/

import acm.program.*;

public class FibonacciSequence extends ConsoleProgram{
     public void run() {     
            int n0 = 1;
            int n1 = 1;
            int n2;    
            println("0" + "\n" + n0 + "\n" + n1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) { // Loop for the next 18 terms
                n2 = n1 + n0; //The next term is the sum of the previous two terms
                println(n2 + " ");       
                n0 = n1; // The first previous number becomes the second previous number...       
                n1 = n2; // ...and the current number becomes the previous number     
            }     
            println();
        }
}
```